# Java Calendar to String returns wrong date

Tags: java, calendar

I have a Calendar instance which is returned from a webservice stub with the following date: 
0001-12-31

But when I use the getTime() method this becomes: 0002-01-02

First I thought this would be caused by the formatter but already the returned Date instance is wrong.

Can someone explain why?

```
if (cal != null) {
        System.out.println(cal.toString());
        DateFormat sqlFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        sqlFormat.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone());  
        String formatted = sqlFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(formatted);
        return formatted;
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste your code?

Comment: 31 December of the year 1?

Comment: Yes - the webservice returns that value

Comment: Can you paste what is in cal.toString()?

Comment: Cal.toString() returns 0001-12-31